# How do I find exactly which query clauses matched for each solr hit?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, solrj

Suppose I have a complex query which is composed of many clauses.

The query clauses can be divided into "strict" clauses and "general search", less important clauses.

I'd like to know, without relying on the relevance score, which docs exactly matched the strict part, i.e. which doc meets all of the exact requirements, and which were considered hits due to the general search.

An example "strict" part of a query -

```
+((+field1.subf1:val1 ConstantScore(field1.subf2.subf3.subf4:"[* TO *]" field1.subf2.subf5:true))^10.0) ((title:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")^0.05) (#((+field1.subf1:val1 ConstantScore(field1.subf2.subf3.subf4:"[* TO *]" field1.subf2.subf5:true))~100^10.0))
```

In Elasticsearch, [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) allow me to tag the strict clauses and then validate for each hit which clause was met.

**How can I accomplish this in Solr?**

Thanks alot,
Ron

{p.s. - I'm using solr 5.3.1 and solrj}

Comment: I have written a Google Chrome plugin that explains Solr Queries  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/solr-query-debugger/gmpkeiamnmccifccnbfljffkcnacmmdl

Answer (score 2):

**My current solution** (in hope of getting feedback and sanity-checked)

To decide for each hit if it is "strict", I do the following:

1. Execute the full query as-is
2. In parallel, execute the same query with an added filter field containing the strict clauses ( *fq=${strict_cluases}* ), retrieving only the document ids (*fl="id"*)
3. For every hit id from query 1, if it appears in query 2 ids, I mark the hit as "strict"

Running two different queries and comparing them introduces a risk of the two result sets being too disjoint (thus making the comparison moot), but I believe it is mitigated by them having the same score, start & rows parameters.

Answer (score 0):

the best option:

1. add &debugQuery=true to your
2. get the debug.explain element of the response
3. and parse it

This is a known issue of Solr, if you look around, you will find tools that already do this parsing (albeit might not suit your language etc):

- Solr Explain: https://github.com/solrpl/explain
- I think I saw some other too, cannot remember now

EDIT: let me propose a totally different approach that you might try:

Don't use debugQuery at all, and for the few top docs you need to handle, do this:

1. create individual Lucene queries for your strict clauses, keep them in memory
2. get the doc, and create a MemoryIndex out of it
3. run all the queries on the doc, and you will find out if the doc matches all strict queries or not

maybe this is faster than using debugQuery...

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thanks!
Do you know how suitable is this for production? Have any idea what the overhead of this would be?

Comment: Overhead should depend on the rows param, so if you are getting a smallish number should not be a big issue, if you are getting thousands of results on the other hand...

Comment: After some testing, even for minimal rows (10), the debugQuery flag caused a 5x increase in latency, so is not suitable for my usecase :(

Comment: ouch...I edited with another approach you might try, maybe it's worth a go

Answer (score 0):

Ron ,

Use the Solr Admin Console . You will find the Query window . Provide your query string and check the debug query . In the response you will find exactly what documents matched and what is the highest score for the best match .You need to see the explanation of the highest score which will tell you what part of query match . Strict or Normal !

[image]